# Discarding values from a original vector in R

Tags: r, vector, gps

Is there any way to discard the values from a vector. 
For example; I have the original vector before processing A={23, 24, 25, 26, 27} after processing i got vector B={25, 26}. Now i want to remove values of vector B from vector A without changing the order of vector A.

I want to do it for longitudes and latitudes points.

Thank you.

Comment: Simply, `A[ !A %in% B]`

Comment: Maybe you need `setdiff(A, B)`.

Comment: `setdiff(A, B)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a <-  c(23,24,25,26,27)
b <-  c(25,26)
elements <- a %in% b
new_vec <- a[! elements]
new_vec

> new_vec
[1] 23 24 27
```

The `%in%` gives us which elements of a are in b.
So, indexing with them (`! elements`) gives us the new vector.